# In Kotlin, what does "::class.simpleName" do?

Tags: kotlin, variable-assignment, type-inference, assignment-operator, type-mismatch

`val var1: Any = "Carmelo Anthony"`

I'm under the impression `::class.simpleName` returns the variable type of an object
when I do the following:

`val var1Type = var1::class.simpleName`
`print(var1Type)`

I get `String` and not `Any`

but when I do this

`val var2: String = var1`

I get a `Type mismatch: inferred type is Any but String was expected`

Comment: Your `var1` is statically typed as `Any`, that's why.

Comment: Can be fixed by the typecast from Any to String:  
`val var2: String = var1 as String`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- In Kotlin, the `::class` operator exists in 2 forms:

  - `TypeName::class` - [which returns a `KClass` object for the *static type* `TypeName`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reflection.html#class-references).
  - `variableName::class` - [which returns a `KClass` object corresponding to the **runtime type**](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reflection.html#bound-class-references) of `variableName`, and *not* `variableName`'s static type. (Kotlin calls this the "bound type" in their documentation).
- In your case, `var1` has a runtime tytpe of `String` but a static type of `Any`.

  - So `var1::class` returns the `KClass` for `String`, not `Any`.
- But Kotlin's type system, like most statically typed languages, does not allow for implicit narrowing conversion (i.e. given a variable `var2` typed as `String`, you cannot assign-to `var2` from another variable (`var3`) statically-typed as `Any`, because `var3` *could* have a runtime type that's completely incompatible with `String`, e.g. an `InputStream` object.

  - ...*even if* it's provable (by following the program by-hand) that the `Any`-typed value will always be a `String`.
  - Fortunately, however, Kotlin's type-checker is modern [and its "Smart cast" feature follows the scope of type-narrowing](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/typecasts.html#smart-casts) when the `is` operator is used, which is neat (TypeScript has it too, I don't think any other language does though).

    - In situations where you can't use Smart-casts or can otherwise *prove* to yourself that a downcast is safe then use the `as` operator to perform an [*unsafe cast*](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/typecasts.html). Like so: `var2: String = var1 as String`.

      - (Somewhat confusingly, other languages use `as` as the operator for *safe* casts, argh).

[In context](https://pl.kotl.in/3CqffZT3H):

```kotlin
fun main() {

    val var1: Any = "Carmelo Anthony"
    val var1Type = var1::class.simpleName
    println("var1's type: " + var1Type) // <-- This will print the *runtime type* of `var1` (String), not its static type (which is `Any`, *not* `String`).

    /*
    val var2: String = var1 // <-- Fails beause `var1` is `Any`, and `Any` is "wider" than `String`, and narrowing conversions always considered unsafe in languages like Kotlin, Java, etc.
    */
    val var2Unsafe: String  = var1 as  String; // <-- Doing this is unsafe because it will throw if `var1` is not a String.
    val var2Safe  : String? = var1 as? String; // <-- Doing this is safe because it `var2Safe` will be null if `var1` is not a String.
    
    println(var2Unsafe)
    println(var2Safe)
}
```

---

If you're familiar with other languages, then here's an incomplete table of equivalent operations and their syntax:

|  | Kotlin | Java | JavaScript | C# | C++ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Get static type | `TypeName::class` | `TypeName.class` | `ConstructorName` | `typeof(TypeName)` | `typeid(TypeName)` |
| Get runtime type | `variableName::class` | `variableName.getClass()` | `typeof variableName` (intrinsics) `variableName.constructor` (objects) | `variableName.GetType()` | `typeid(variableName)` |
| Get type from name (string) | `Class.forName( typeName ).kotlin` | `Class.forName( typeName )` | `eval( typeName )` (never do this) |  |  |
| Statically-defined runtime type check | `variableName is TypeName` | `variableName instanceof TypeName` | `typeof variableName === 'typeName'` (intrinsics) or `variableName instanceof ConstructorName` (objects) | `variableName is TypeName` |  |
| Runtime dynamic type check | `otherKClass.isInstance( variableName )` or `otherKType.isSubtypeOf()` | `otherClass.isAssignableFrom( variableName.getClass() )` |  | `otherType.IsAssignableFrom( variableName.GetType() )` |  |
| Unsafe narrowing (aka downcast) | `val n: NarrowType = widerVar as NarrowType;` | `NarrowType n = (NarrowType)widerVar;` | `variableName as TypeName` (TypeScript only) | `NarrowType n = (NarrowType)widerVar;` |  |
| Safe narrowing (downcast or `null`) | `val n: NarrowType? = widerVar as? NarrowType;` |  |  | `NarrowType n? = widerVar as NarrowType;` | `dynamic_cast<NarrowType>( widerVar )` |
| Conditional narrowing in scope | `variableName is TypeName` |  | `func(x: unknown): x is TypeName` guard functions (TypeScript only) | `widerVar is TypeName n` |  |

---